# Hide Matplotlib grid color

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I'd like to hide the 3d grid background color and just display gridlines and axis labels, as it's currently the default gray color
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGrXg.png) (Not allowed to embed images since this is a new account). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can set the background color to black.

```
ax.set_facecolor("black")
```

https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/color/color_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-color-demo-py

Comment: The facecolor is already black, hence the black background. I'm trying to change the grid specifically